# Writing byteArrays into a file issue

Tags: java, file, arrays, assertion

So I have a couple of methods and when I test them using an assertion test it fails, and I can't for the life of me figure out why, so if anyone can help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The methods are supposed to write a block into an existing file, then read said block and make sure that the assertion works.

The Write Method:

```
public void writeBlock(int blockNum, AbstractDBFile f, AbstractBlock b)
            throws IOException {

        DBFile dbf = (DBFile) f;
        Block blk = (Block) b;

        if (blockNum >= dbf.totalNumOfBlocks){
            dbf.totalNumOfBlocks++;
        }
        int header = 4096;
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dbf.fileName, "rw");
        file.seek(header + (blockNum) * 4096);
        file.write(blk.getData(), 0, 4096);
        file.close();
        f.curBlockPos = blockNum + 1;


    }
```

The Read Method:

```
public AbstractBlock readBlock(int blockNum, AbstractDBFile f)
        throws IOException {

    f.setCurBlockPos(blockNum); 
    DBFile f2 = new DBFile();
    f2.setCurBlockPos(f.getCurBlockPos());
    f2.setFileName(f.getFileName());
    Block block = new Block();

    int currentByte = f2.getCurBlockPos() * 4096;
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
    String filename = f2.getFileName();
    File ourFile = new File(filename);

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(ourFile, "r");
    FileChannel inChannel = file.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(currentByte);
    inChannel.read(bb);
    while(inChannel.read(bb)>0){
    bb.flip();
    for (int i =0; i<bb.limit(); i++){
        data[i]=bb.get();
        block.setData(data);
    }
    bb.clear();
}
    inChannel.close();
    file.close();
    return block;

}
```

The Block Class:

```
public class Block extends AbstractBlock {

    @Override
    public byte[] getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*byte[] data = new byte [4096];
        data[0] = 10;
        data[5] = 20;*/
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(byte[] d) throws IOException {
        int freeByte = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length && freeByte < 0; i++)
            if(data[i] == 0)
                freeByte = i;

        for(int i = freeByte, j = 0; j < d.length; i++, j++)
            data[i] = d[j];
    }
    }
```

The Assertion test:

```
 public void testWriteRead() throws IOException {
           StorageManager manager = new StorageManager();
           DBFile file = (DBFile)manager.createFile("File1");

           byte [] write = new byte[4096];
           write[0] = 10;
           write[5] = 20;

           Block block = new Block();
           block.setData(write);

           manager.writeBlock(0, file, block);

           Block b = (Block) manager.readBlock(0, file);
           assertTrue(areEqual(write,b.getData()));
       }
private boolean areEqual(byte [] array1, byte [] array2) {
           if(array1.length != array2.length)
               return false;
           for(int i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++)
               if(array1[i] != array2[i])
                   return false;
           return true;
       }
```

I wont be doing this if I was not desperate, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about the arrays is not equal? The length or the element values?

Comment: @AndyTurner Element values is the issue

Comment: Can I suggest that you add an assertion to see if the data is correct after the `setData` call (before `writeBlock`)? I'm not sure that it will be.

Comment: Don't you use Java 7+? If yes: 1. use JSR 203, and 2. use try-with-resources

Comment: @AndyTurner setData is correct

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm beginning to feel that the read method maybe wrong, did you spot something fishy about the code? I'm positive the write and the set are correct, the read is probably wrong